Batch MS-DOS para copiar (o renombrar) archivo con el nombre escrito por el usuario
Estoy intentado crear un batch para automatizar el proceso de creación de imágenes de disquete formateadas en DOSBox Pure, para usarla en algunos juegos que necesitan cargar datos desde el Floppy.
La idea es copiar una imagen vacía (FD360K.IMG, FD1440K.IMG, etc.) de la carpeta "C:\FDs" a "C:" con el comando "choise", e introducir el nombre nuevo manualmente.
O copiar a un archivo cualquiera (tmp.IMG) posteriormente cambiarlo introduciendo el nuevo nombre.
Y para finalizar formatear con "format.exe a:" (de FreeDOS) que pide introducir al final la etiqueta.
He podido conseguir copiar y formatear pero me ha sido imposible hacer que el usuario introduzca el nombre.
¿Es posible hacerlo en DOSBox o con apoyo algún programa de FreeDOS?

No veo porque no... esos dos son solo portables del sistema operativo DOS original para que funcione en una ventana.. por lo cual si es posible...
